# Как удалить первые 5 символов в нечётных\чётных строках memo

Tags: delphi

Как удалить первые 5 символов в нечётных строках memo? И ещё покажите пример как это сделать с чётными...

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум 3 варианта проверки на чётность/нечётность. Число `a` чётное, когда:

```
(a mod 2)=0;
odd(a)=false;
(a and 1)=0;
```

Удалить первые 5 символов из строки `str` можно так:

```
delete(str, 1, 5);
```

p.s.: а еще можно идти через одну строчку и попадать только на чётные/нечётные.

Answer (score 1):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:integer;
    str:string;
begin
  i:=0;
  while (i<=(Memo1.Lines.Count-1)) do
  begin
    str:=Memo1.Lines[i];
    Delete(str, 1, 5);
    Memo1.Lines[i]:=str;
    i:=i+2;
  end;
end;
```

Начиная с i:=0 - удаляем в нечётных, если начать с i:=1, то удалим в чётных строках